# jQuery selector only if parent doesn't have attr

Tags: javascript, jquery

Imagine I have this:

```
<span email="a@test.com" class="parent">
     <div class="child"></div>
</span>
<span email="b@test.com" class="parent">
     <div class="child"></div>
</span>
```

How I would I find only the `.child` elements where the parent span attr `email` is NOT `b@test.com`?

Comment: find all emails then `).find('.child')` maybe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it:

```
$('.parent[email!="b@test.com"] .child');
```

[Source](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/).

Regards.

Comment: According to [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/), "*Because `[name!="value"]` is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using `[name!="value"]` cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM `querySelectorAll()` method. For better performance in modern browsers, use `$( "your-pure-css-selector" ).not( "[name='value']" )` instead.*"

Answer (score 2):

Use this selector:

```
$(".parent:not([email='b@test.com']) .child")
```

You can use .each to get each element:

```
$(".parent:not([email='b@test.com']) .child").each(function(){
    var item = $(this); // get the current element
    // do something
});
```

Comment: `b@test.com` is not a CSS [identifier](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier). Therefore, `[email=b@test.com]` won't work. Either use the string `[email="b@test.com"]` string, or escape `[email=b\@test\.com]`.

Answer (score 2):

It's simple as this:

```
$('[email][email!="b@test.com"] > .child')
```

**Explanation:**
With this you find all elements with class `child` which have a parent (`>`) with email attribute (`[email]`) and this email attribute is not `b@test.com` (`[email!="b@test.com"]`).

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4xb0c4e9/)

Comment: According to [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/), "*Because `[name!="value"]` is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using `[name!="value"]` cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM `querySelectorAll()` method. For better performance in modern browsers, use `$( "your-pure-css-selector" ).not( "[name='value']" )` instead.*"

Answer (score 1):

Just use one of those selectors:

```css
.parent:not([email="b@test.com"]) > .child
.parent:not([email=b\@test\.com]) > .child
```

```css
.parent:not([email="b@test.com"]) > .child {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<span email="a@test.com" class="parent">
     <div class="child">A</div>
</span>
<span email="b@test.com" class="parent">
     <div class="child">B</div>
</span>
```

If you want to get them all with JS, use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.parent:not([email="b@test.com"]) > .child')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.find("span[email !='b@test.com'] .child");
```

Comment: According to [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/), "*Because `[name!="value"]` is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using `[name!="value"]` cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM `querySelectorAll()` method. For better performance in modern browsers, use `$( "your-pure-css-selector" ).not( "[name='value']" )` instead.*"